# How to upload many images to the server using Apache Jmeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter

I have an application it will upload every captured images to the server. Now I have to perform server performance testing. I have to verify how it will perform if 100 devices are trying to upload the photos to same server at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider next few things:

1. Add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) with relevant User-Agent string to simulate mobile browser or application.
2. Make sure that POST request is being used and the "Use multipart/form-data for POST" box is checked.

See [Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) guide for detailed walkthrough.